# Force different orientation for ipad/iphone in rubymotion

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, rubymotion, device-orientation

I have an iOS Universal App, and I need to use it with:

- LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight for iPad
- Portrait for iPhone

Let's take the iPad for example, I need to force the app to open in landscape mode, even if the user's device is in portrait mode. This was working flawless, when the app was only for iPad and the rakefile used this setting:

```
app.interface_orientations = [:landscape_left, : landscape_right]
```

Unfortunately, now, with that removed, the app shows up by default in portrait mode. I tried to change this by overwriting the following methods in UIViewController.rb. This works on the simulator, but not on my device:

```
  def shouldAutorotate
    # Block AutoRotation if the interfaces is CORRECT
    # Else allow IT
    if Device.ipad? # BubbleWrap gem method 
      if App.shared.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
        return false
      elsif App.shared.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    elsif Device.iphone?
      if App.shared.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  def viewDidAppear(animated)
    # Change the orientation after the view Appeared
    if Device.ipad?
      App.shared.setStatusBarOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    elsif Device.iphone?
      App.shared.setStatusBarOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    end
  end
```

I tried a lot of solutions, and none seem to work the way I want.

Thanks, Vlad

Answer (score 0):

To try and simplify everything, you could use the [motion-schemes wrapper](https://github.com/siuying/motion-schemes) which will let you setup different settings for each device, which means you can go back to the simplicity of `app.interface_orientations` and avoid all the hackery.